# Unity3D - Add custom headers to WWWForm

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

***Here is the C# Code I ran:***

```
WWWForm formData = new WWWForm ();

//Adding
formData.headers.Add ("Authorization", "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CONSUMER_KEY + ":" + CONSUMER_SECRET)));
formData.headers.Add ("Host", "api.twitter.com");

//Assigning
formData.headers ["Host"] = "api.twitter.com";
formData.headers ["Authorization"] = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (CONSUMER_KEY + ":" + CONSUMER_SECRET));

Debug.Log (formData.headers ["Authorization"]);
```

As shown above, I tried to add `Authorization` and `Host` fields to the header and then Assigning them values just to be sure. However Unity3D throws a Error on `formData.headers ["Authorization"]` everytime.

***Here is the Error Message:***

```
KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String].get_Item (System.String key) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:150)
Information+Twitter.GetToken () (at Assets/Static Libraries/Information.cs:143)
Information.Initialize () (at Assets/Static Libraries/Information.cs:18)
WorldScript.Awake () (at Assets/WorldScript.cs:16)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`WWWForm.headers`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm-headers.html) variable is read only. When you call the `Add`  function, it's not really adding anything. That's why you are getting that error because the data is not added to the [`WWWForm.headers`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm-headers.html).

Unity's `WWW` class changed recently. To add headers, you have to create Dictionary then pass that `Dictionary` to the third parameter of the `WWW` constructor.

```
public WWW(string url, byte[] postData, Dictionary<string, string> headers);
```

Something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 55.0.2883.87 Safari / 537.36");

WWW www = new WWW("http://www.thismachine.info/", null, headers);
yield return www;
Debug.Log(www.text);
```

---

If you have form to post, you can use a combination of `WWWForm` and `Dictionary` to do that. Just convert the `WWWForm` to array with [`WWWForm.data`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm-data.html) then pass it to the second parameter of the `WWW` constructor.

```
Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 55.0.2883.87 Safari / 537.36");

WWWForm formData = new WWWForm();
formData.AddField("UserName", "Programmer");
formData.AddField("Password", "ProgrammerPass");

WWW www = new WWW("http://www.thismachine.info/", formData.data, headers);
yield return www;
Debug.Log(www.text);
```

Comment: It's strange that mutating a read-only object doesn't give me a error or a warning.

Comment: I know it's wired. Either each time you access `WWWForm.headers`, you are given a new instance/copy of `Dictionary` or Unity has a code that removes anything from the `Dictionary`. I can't tell what exactly is going on unless I have the source code.